# Setting RouterLink for Select in angular > 4.x.x

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, routes, html-select

I am trying to build an app in Angular 6.1.2 in which user can select an option from a drop-down and see the desired result. So far, I am able to achieve the drop-down but I am having some problem in understanding:

> How to set the [routerLink] for it.

I am sharing the details with you:

**The Background**

```
Angular Version: 6.1.2,
```

Related Code:

```
 <div class="col-6 navigationLanguageCol">
          <select ng-model="languages" (change)="languageSelected($event)">
            <option value=" ">Languages</option>
            <option *ngFor="let language of Languages">{{ language.name }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
          </select>
          <p>
            Languaged: {{ selectedLanguage }}
          </p>
        </div>
```

.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Router Module for Application level Route
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Terra';

  public Languages;
  public selectedLanguage;


  constructor(private router: RouterModule) {
    this.Languages = [

      { "code": "ab", "name": "Abkhaz", "nativeName": "аҧсуа" },
      { "code": "aa", "name": "Afar", "nativeName": "Afaraf" },
      { "code": "af", "name": "Afrikaans", "nativeName": "Afrikaans" },
      { "code": "ak", "name": "Akan", "nativeName": "Akan" },
      { "code": "sq", "name": "Albanian", "nativeName": "Shqip" },
      { "code": "am", "name": "Amharic", "nativeName": "አማርኛ" },
      { "code": "ar", "name": "Arabic", "nativeName": "العربية" },
      { "code": "an", "name": "Aragonese", "nativeName": "Aragonés" },
      { "code": "hy", "name": "Armenian", "nativeName": "Հայերեն" },
      { "code": "as", "name": "Assamese", "nativeName": "অসমীয়া" },
      { "code": "av", "name": "Avaric", "nativeName": "авар мацӀ, магӀарул мацӀ" },
      { "code": "ae", "name": "Avestan", "nativeName": "avesta" },
      { "code": "ay", "name": "Aymara", "nativeName": "aymar aru" },
      { "code": "az", "name": "Azerbaijani", "nativeName": "azərbaycan dili"}      
    ]
  }

  languageSelected(event: any) {
    this.selectedLanguage = event.target.value;
  }

}
```

**The Problem**

I want to set [routerLink] inside navigationLanguageCol but not able to understand how to do so. I tried looking online but nothing seems to work

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's no `[routerLink]` in your code.

Comment: Hi, yes I removed it because when I add `[routerLink]="['/language']"` to `<option></option>`, It stops displaying the languages in dropdown.

Comment: Because options aren't made to be links ... Bind the navigation to the `(change)` event, with adding `this.router.navigate([event.target.value])` to the function.

Comment: routerlink are not suppossed to use with the select they are either used in anchor tag  or a button. In your case you can just add a this.router.navigate(['event.target.value']) in your languageSelected method

Comment: Thanks for your help.